# Xuggler - add audio?

Tags: java, audio, video, mp3, xuggle

I creating an video file by encoding BufferedImages. How I can add Audio to this video from mp3 file?

```
IMediaWriter movie = ToolFactory.makeWriter("somefile.mp4");                
movie.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, 720, 540);
movie.encodeVideo(0,img, time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);   
movie.close();
```

When I try concatenate class I get this error:

```
45694 [Thread-2] WARN com.xuggle.xuggler - Got error: picture is not of the same PixelType as this Coder expected (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1430)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the example at [xuggle](http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ConcatenateAudioAndVideo.java?r=929)

```
writer.addAudioStream(audioStreamIndex, audioStreamId, channelCount,
      sampleRate);
```

Comment: @goodm Have you gone through the sample at http://code.google.com/p/xuggle/source/browse/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/ConcatenateAudioAndVideo.java?r=929

Comment: there is example how to connect two files, I want to create video and during this process add audio. Not load again saved video.

Comment: @goodm What image type you are using? please pass the code, where you are populating the image[img variable in the snippet]. If you are using BufferedImage then, create the BufferedImage with BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR instead of BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB

Comment: I manage to add mp3 file to the video, I'm working right now with how to crop the mp3.

Comment: grt! If you feel that the whole conversation has helped you, mark it as correct answer.